# Git not seeing files in folders in newly initiated repo. Is it normal?

Tags: git, git-status

I have an existing folder containing a hole hierarchy of subfolders, some of them containing files.

I `cd` into this folder, and then do `git init .`.

If I immediately do `git status`, only the direct entries in the directory appear, not their content:

```
bli@naples:/tmp$ mkdir repo
bli@naples:/tmp$ mkdir repo/subfolder1
bli@naples:/tmp$ mkdir repo/subfolder2
bli@naples:/tmp$ touch repo/file1
bli@naples:/tmp$ touch repo/subfolder1/file11
bli@naples:/tmp$ touch repo/subfolder2/file21
bli@naples:/tmp$ cd repo
bli@naples:/tmp/repo$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /tmp)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
bli@naples:/tmp/repo$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/.git/
bli@naples:/tmp/repo$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    file1
    subfolder1/
    subfolder2/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I think I remember `git status` used to show subfolder contents. Did I dream that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subfolders currently aren't tracked by git, so `git status` won't show their content. Once you add the first file under the subfolder, you'll also see information about the untracked files in that subfolder.

Comment: You can use `--untracked-files=all` option (or set `status.showUntrackedFiles` config to `all` for permanent behavior) to force git to show files in untracked directories (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status---untracked-filesltmodegt)